# How to optimize feature vector extraction of images in training dataset?

Tags: python, image-processing, feature-extraction

this is my code to retrieve a set of feature vectors from training data.However, when running on Kaggle, I don't have enough memory, can anyone tell me how to optimize this function?

````
def save_trained_file_feature_vectors(feat_extractor, save_path):
    # Proprocessing image
    importedImages = []

    for f in train_files:
        filename = f
        original = load_img(filename, target_size=(imgs_model_width, imgs_model_height))
        numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
        image_batch = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, axis=0)

        importedImages.append(image_batch)

    images = np.vstack(importedImages)
    processed_imgs = preprocess_input(images.copy())

    # Extract and save features
    imgs_features = feat_extractor.predict(processed_imgs)
    np.save(save_path, imgs_features)
    return imgs_features```
````

I tried using Dask Datagram to compute it, but it seemed to not work well.
I use 15k image in this dataset

[Mydata](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/paramaggarwal/fashion-product-images-dataset/code?resource=download)

Comment: so you're loading the whole dataset into RAM... can you work on it without having to load it all into RAM at once? can you use memory mapping of decompressed/uncompressed data?

Comment: Also, how much memory does it need, and can you just solve the problem by buying more memory?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz , i am working on recommender system for image. My goal is to get a list of feature vectors of the training images, so when user input image, the model will extract it and compute similarity score based on Cosine then get k highest ones. For this, i just need to run this function one time when there is no feature vectors list saved.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i need 16gb but the maximum ram on Kaggle is 13.